# How to set the language in a html document via r markdown html

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using a .Rmd documment and rendering to html_document. The prefix of my tables come as "Table", however, I want it in my first language. As in pdf_document, I want to set the language of my report to portuguese, like this:

```
---
title: "Code"
author: "Guilherme"
date: "May 9, 2017" 
lang: "pt-br"
output:
  html_document: default
---
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: How do you add your table prefix? your YAML front matter doesn't produce any.

Comment: If you use bookdown to get your table/fig references, then internationalization is shown on this page: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/internationalization.html

Comment: Hy @scoa, I use this command `options(table_counter = TRUE, width = 10000)` in my report, which counts which table is. The command that I use to generate the table itfself is `htmlTable(..., caption="Descriptive Measuraments of...")`. It creates the caption: Table1: Descriptive Measuraments of....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I knit:

````
---
title: "Code"
author: "Guilherme"
date: "May 9, 2017" 
lang: "pt-br"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r cars}
library(knitr)
kable(mtcars[1:5,2:3], caption = "Azul")
```
````

with a file called `_bookdown.yml` in the same directory with this content:

```
language:
  label:
    fig: "Figura "
    tab: "Tabela "
```

it produces the labeling correctly, as @Sébastian suggested in the comments

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with the `htmlTable` package because the "Table no" bit is hardcoded into this package (see the [source code](https://github.com/gforge/htmlTable/blob/master/R/htmlTable_helpers.R#L24)).

If you want localization, thus, you'll need to use another way to produce captions. An alternative is the [captioner package](https://github.com/adletaw/captioner).

````
```{r}
library(htmlTable)
library(captioner)

table_nums <- captioner(prefix = "Tabela") # from google translate :)

htmlTable(table(iris$Species,iris$Species), 
          caption = table_nums("desc_iris", "Descriptive Measuraments of..."))
```
````