# Is there a way to inform the configuration file in bookdown YAML in another directory in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, bookdown

In `R Markdown` we can inform `css`, `csl` and `bibliograph` as external files.

If I want to use a `configuration file` I need to keep it into the same directory as `.Rmd` as it is described in https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/usage.html and an example is provided in my answer here: [How to set the language in a html document via r markdown html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871475/how-to-set-the-language-in-a-html-document-via-r-markdown-html/43875710#43875710)

However, Can I keep the `_bookdown.yml` file in another directory of my `.Rmd` file and inform it like `includes` or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible as inside `render_book` we have:

```
config = load_config()  # configurations in _bookdown.yml
```

where `load_config` is using `.` directory.

```
load_config = function() {
  if (length(opts$get('config')) == 0 && file.exists('_bookdown.yml')) {
    # store the book config
    opts$set(config = rmarkdown:::yaml_load_file('_bookdown.yml'))
  }
```

Source: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown

Comment: I know that the purpose of `bookdown` is to write `books`. However, I am planning it to write many reports. It would be nice if I could just inform one path... Thank you @polkas

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39885363/importing-common-yaml-in-rstudio-knitr-document check this out and especially pandoc_args

Comment: Tks. But it seems that it is not possible to pass those info from `_bookdown.yml` to `YAML`

Comment: Yes, pandoc_args is not helping in the case of _bookdown.yml, I wrote why in the answer. It could be helpful in other cases for the future that is why I sent it to you.

Comment: You want the YAML file to be able to be included at the top of the page from outside the Rmd?

Comment: No @DanielJachetta, I just want to inform the full path of `_bookdown.yml` inside to YAML (like with bib files), instead of keeping it into the same folder as the `.Rmd` file